# Set Default User / Group (Sticky Bit) in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, chmod

To enforce the following permissions on files in /var/www, can I use the commands chmod u+s and chmod g+s?

Permissions:

chown -R root:web /var/www
chmod -R g+rw /var/www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `setgid` bit on a directory will cause files and directories to inherit the group ownership of that directory.  It will not have any impact on file or directory permissions.

File and directory permissions are controlled primarily by the process `umask`, which you can set for example in the Apache startup script.

To do what you want, you would first need to recursively set the `setgid` bit on all the directories in `/var/www`, *and* would would need to fix the permissions on existing files, *and* you would need to make sure all the existing files/directories have appropriate user and group ownership, *and* you would need to arrange for Apache to use the appropriate umask.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user) for more information about setting the umask for Apache.

Comment: Thanks! What are your thoughts on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000023/are-these-lamp-permissions-secure

Comment: I've added some comments on that question.